How to align particles to have same direction as parent and rotate around Z axis
I am making a city model, where I want to generate homes based on weight painted ground mesh. However I can't align particle homes to be facing the same way up as the parent model. I want the alignment to be with Z up, and rotation around Z axis. No option of Normal/Tangent/Global XYZ/Local XYZ does that. They either have wrong alignment or wrong rotation axis.
I know the trick with rotating the model, but I want to apply (bought) geometry nodes that would generate details, and it relies on Z being up (otherwise roof would be on the side and windows on top).
How can I do this without rotating the model? Is this even possible with particle system?



maybe parenting the house to an empty and then rotating it could work

Is there any motivation not to use geometry nodes instead of particles ? Especially for a static setup, it would let you do that kind of thing with total control. Consider sharing your blend file so that we don't have to guess your setup : https://blend-exchange.com/.

The motivation is that I know particles way better than geometry nodes. I thought this is a common enough question that there should be an easy fix, but it seems that it's just blender being blender.
